# Why my data uploaded for "dataImage" swaps to "dataStock" in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I added a new child node in firebase "datastock" and give a unique view id in android so that the data will be uploaded exactly to their respective child node. Unfortunately, it still swaps the data for "dataImage" into "dataStock",
[[image: firebase data]]

Even though I already check many times for the possibility that their view id's was swapped. Tell me what I'm missing out, here's my code:

activity_upload.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".UploadActivity">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
        app:cardElevation="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/lavender_border">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Upload Data"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/lavender"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:src="@drawable/uploadimg"
                android:id="@+id/uploadImage"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:id="@+id/uploadTopic"
                android:background="@drawable/lavender_border"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:hint="Enter product name"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/lavender"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:id="@+id/uploadDesc"
                android:background="@drawable/lavender_border"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:hint="Enter description"
                android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/lavender"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:id="@+id/uploadLang"
                android:background="@drawable/lavender_border"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:hint="Enter price"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/lavender"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:id="@+id/uploadStock"
                android:background="@drawable/lavender_border"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:hint="Enter stock"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/lavender"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="Save"
                android:id="@+id/saveButton"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:cornerRadius = "20dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</ScrollView>
```

UploadActivity.java

```
package com.example.admin_app;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Currency;

public class UploadActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView uploadImage;
    Button saveButton;
    EditText uploadTopic, uploadDesc, uploadLang, uploadStock;
    String imageURL;
    Uri uri;
    //CurrencyEditText uploadLang;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);
        
        uploadImage = findViewById(R.id.uploadImage);
        uploadDesc = findViewById(R.id.uploadDesc);
        uploadTopic = findViewById(R.id.uploadTopic);
        uploadLang = findViewById(R.id.uploadLang);
        uploadStock = findViewById(R.id.uploadStock);
        saveButton = findViewById(R.id.saveButton);

        ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                        if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                            Intent data = result.getData();
                            assert data != null;
                            uri = data.getData();
                            uploadImage.setImageURI(uri);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "No Image Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
        );

        uploadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent photoPicker = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                photoPicker.setType("image/*");
                activityResultLauncher.launch(photoPicker);
            }
        });

        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                saveData();
            }
        });
    }

    public void saveData(){

        StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Android Images")
                .child(uri.getLastPathSegment());

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UploadActivity.this);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setView(R.layout.progress_layout);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

        storageReference.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                Task<Uri> uriTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                while (!uriTask.isComplete());
                Uri urlImage = uriTask.getResult();
                imageURL = urlImage.toString();
                uploadData();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

    public void uploadData(){

        String title = uploadTopic.getText().toString();
        String desc = uploadDesc.getText().toString();
        String lang = uploadLang.getText().toString();
        String stock = uploadStock.getText().toString();

        DataClass dataClass = new DataClass(title, desc, lang, stock, imageURL);

        //We are changing the child from title to currentDate,
        // because we will be updating title as well and it may affect child value.

        String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Products").child(currentDate)
                .setValue(dataClass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

MyAdapter.java

```
package com.example.admin_app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<DataClass> dataList;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<DataClass> dataList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.dataList = dataList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Glide.with(context).load(dataList.get(position).getDataImage()).into(holder.recImage);
        holder.recTitle.setText(dataList.get(position).getDataTitle());
        holder.recDesc.setText(dataList.get(position).getDataDesc());
        holder.recLang.setText(dataList.get(position).getDataLang());
        holder.recStock.setText(dataList.get(position).getDataStock());
        holder.recCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Image", dataList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getDataImage());
                intent.putExtra("Description", dataList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getDataDesc());
                intent.putExtra("Name", dataList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getDataTitle());
                intent.putExtra("Key",dataList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getKey());
                intent.putExtra("Price", dataList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getDataLang());
                intent.putExtra("Stock", dataList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getDataStock());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }

    public void searchDataList(ArrayList<DataClass> searchList){
        dataList = searchList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView recImage;
    TextView recTitle, recDesc, recLang, recStock;
    CardView recCard;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        recImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recImage);
        recCard = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recCard);
        recDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recDesc);
        recLang = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recPriority);
        recTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recTitle);
        recStock = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recStock);
    }
}
```

DataClass.java

```
package com.example.admin_app;


public class DataClass {

    private String dataTitle;
    private String dataDesc;
    private String dataLang;
    private String dataImage;
    private String dataStock;
    private String key;

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getDataTitle() {
        return dataTitle;
    }

    public String getDataDesc() {
        return dataDesc;
    }

    public String getDataLang() {
        return dataLang;
    }
    public String getDataStock() {
        return dataStock;
    }

    public String getDataImage() {
        return dataImage;
    }

    public DataClass(String dataTitle, String dataDesc, String dataLang, String dataImage, String dataStock) {
        this.dataTitle = dataTitle;
        this.dataDesc = dataDesc;
        this.dataLang = dataLang;
        this.dataImage = dataImage;
        this.dataStock = dataStock;
    }
    public DataClass(){

    }
}
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted more than **400** (four hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped. Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I didn't post all of my code here, I post only the class that I think is relevant to my problem, I'll try to post minimal code anyway.